# ProgressDialog new Activity Asynctask is not showing, why?

Tags: java, android-activity, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I made a AsyncTask class with the following code

```
public class removeDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

Context c;
ProgressDialog asyncDialog;
String page;

public removeDialog(Context c, String page) {
    this.c = c;
    this.page = page;

    asyncDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //set message of the dialog
    asyncDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
    asyncDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    asyncDialog.setCancelable(false);
    //show dialog
    asyncDialog.show();

    if (page == "algemeneVoorwaarden") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(c, algemeneVoorwaarden.class);
        c.startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (page == "contact") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(c, contactTest.class);
        c.startActivity(intent);
    }

    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    //don't touch dialog here it'll break the application
    //do some lengthy stuff like calling login webservice

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    //hide the dialog
    asyncDialog.dismiss();

    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

First time I tried:
on the first time I see an ProgressDialog, but the second time I want to open the activity I get nothing.

Second time I tried:
I get no ProgressDialog even the first time I try.

I execute my code in an AsyncTask class, code:

```
voorwaarden.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new removeDialog(c, "algemeneVoorwaarden").execute();
            }
        });
```

Does someone know why it isn't working? Please help me.

Comment: Is `removeDialog` the name of your AsyncTask derived class? It would be nice if you could post the header of your class.

Comment: It's the name of the class.

Comment: Ok. Well, in your `onPreExecute`, you're showing the dialog and starting a new activity. I can be wrong, but I think your dialog is shown inside the first activity, so when you start a new one, your dialog is left behind.

Comment: Hmm, do you know any other idea how to do it?

Comment: I tried with: ThreadSleep and I got a little bit further. The ProgressDialog is working on the background, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Oh, damn.. I hadn't realized it.. Your `doInBackground` was empty, so of course, the dialog would be dismissed in no time.

Comment: I fixed it. I just did ThreadSleep for 3 seconds and I tried to go as fast as possible back to the activity, but it's still gone.

Comment: Do you want points? Just write some code with ThreadSleep, Boolean and Integer

Comment: Try this: leave the `dismiss` and the `Thread.sleep`, but comment those lines `c.startActivity(intent)`.

Comment: I wrote this in the background: int i = 2;
        while(running){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(i-- == 0){
                running = false;
            }
        }

        return null;

Comment: I think that should not be the problem. `Thread.sleep(5000)` or so would be just fine. It's very strange that the dialog won't go away even with that `dismiss` statement.

Comment: It will go away with dismiss, but he does this immediately, so I added the Thread.Sleep() and now it works.

Comment: And '5000' for Thread.Sleep() is too long

Comment: So it works now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice! You're welcome!

Comment: If you want some points: you could add that code of me in the comment in the: 'doInBackground(Void... arg0)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog will be dismissed as soon as it's shown, because your `doInBackground` is empty. Try adding a `Thread.sleep()` with a few seconds, just to simulate a delay.

Also, I suspect that the new activities you're starting will leave your dialog behind. So I would suggest you to test the code without these new activities for now.

```
public class RemoveDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog asyncDialog;

    public RemoveDialog(Context c) {
        asyncDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //set message of the dialog
        asyncDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        asyncDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        asyncDialog.setCancelable(false);

        //show dialog
        asyncDialog.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //hide the dialog
        asyncDialog.dismiss();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```